# Is there a way to use Typescript.Collections.HashTable in my code?

Tags: typescript

I see in the code of the Typescript compiler, an implementation of "HashTable" (in the files src/compiler/core/hashTable.ts).

Do you know is there a way I can use it directly in my Typescript project ?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so, what did you do?

Answer (score 27):

You can implement a very simple hashtable where the key is a string by defining an interface

```
class Person {
    name: string;
}

interface HashTable<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

var persons: HashTable<Person> = {};
persons["bob"] = new Person();
var bob = persons["bob"];
```

It can only be keyed on a string or a number though.

Comment: Would the process be more difficult/verbose if we had to key on a more complex object rather than a string or a number? You'd think TypeScript would ship with a built-in dictionary data structure...

Comment: Well, typescript doesn't ship with anything, it's just compile-time checking. So we are at the mercy of javascript.

Comment: You don't have to make a whole HashTable type for it: `var persons: { [key: string]: Person } = {};`

Answer (score 4):

I get socked with people trying to reinvent the wheel.

Typescript is a superset of Javascript, meaning that any Javascript works as well.

In Javascript you have Map() which is not 100% like an hashtable but has similiar usage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections

One thing to beaware is the fact that the implementation of Map here lets you set the same key multiple times, where it overrides the old value.

One function I've made and use to avoid this is the following:

```
private add<K,V>(map:Map<K,V>, key:K, value:V){
    if(map.has(key)){
        throw new TypeError("Key "+ key +" already exists!");
    }else{
        map.set(key,value);
    }
}
```

I pass it a map I define previously by doing something like:

```
MyMap = new Map();
```

or

```
MyMapStrict = new Map<string,string>();
```

And than pass a key and a value that must respect the map key and value types. Otherwise Typescript compiler will throw an error.

Example:

```
add(MyMapStrict, "myKey", "myvalue");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Download the file "hashTable.ts" and put it right next to your file. Then at the top of your file do:

```
///<reference path='hashTable.ts' />
```

PS: I would recommend having a [look at a lib](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections) `TypeScript Generic Collections` I authored. Here is a dictionary sample:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string, public yearOfBirth: number,public city?:string) {
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name + "-" + this.yearOfBirth; // City is not a part of the key. 
    }
}

class Car {
    constructor(public company: string, public type: string, public year: number) {
    }
    toString() {
        // Short hand. Adds each own property 
        return collections.toString(this);
    }
}
var dict = new collections.Dictionary<Person, Car>();
dict.setValue(new Person("john", 1970,"melbourne"), new Car("honda", "city", 2002));
dict.setValue(new Person("gavin", 1984), new Car("ferrari", "F50", 2006));
console.log("Orig");
console.log(dict);

// Changes the same john, since city is not part of key 
dict.setValue(new Person("john", 1970, "sydney"), new Car("honda", "accord", 2006)); 
// Add a new john
dict.setValue(new Person("john", 1971), new Car("nissan", "micra", 2010)); 
console.log("Updated");
console.log(dict);

// Showing getting / setting a single car: 
console.log("Single Item");
var person = new Person("john", 1970); 
console.log("-Person:");
console.log(person);

var car = dict.getValue(person);
console.log("-Car:");
console.log(car.toString());
```

Comment: Is this still the best solution for type hashtables? Or do they have something similar in the core typescript now? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidThielen sorry for the late notice : TypeScript does not ship with a *standard* library (like the BCL for .net).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://narayanatechnicalworld.blogspot.com.eg/2016/05/collections-in-typescript.html) blog post, TypeScript defines a `Map` interface which seems similar to a `HashTable`

other collections

- WeakMap
- Set
- WeakSet