# Is there any defined HashTable class in TypeScript like C#

Tags: javascript, typescript, hashtable, typescript2.0

I am developing web project using TypeScript. Here i need **HashTable** functionality in typescript like **C# HashTable**. But i have already developed that in *JavaScript*.

```
        this.length = 0;
    this.items = [];
    this.add = function (key, value) {
        this.previous = undefined;
        if (this.containsKey(key)) {
            this.previous = this.items[key];
        } else {
            this.length++;
        }
        this.items[key] = value;
        return this.previous;
    };
    this.clear = function () {
        this.items = {};
        this.length = 0;
    };
    this.contains = function (key) {
        return this.items.hasOwnProperty(key);
    };
    this.containsKey = function (key) {
        return this.items.hasOwnProperty(key);
    };
    this.containsValue = function (key) {
        return (this.items.hasOwnProperty(key) && this.items[key] != undefined) ? true : false;
    };
    this.getItem = function (key) {
        if (this.containsKey(key))
        {

            return this.items[key]
        }
        else
        {
            return  undefined;
        }
    };
    this.keys = function () {
        var keys = [];
        for (var k in this.items) {
            if (this.containsKey(k)) {
                keys.push(k);
            }
        }
        return keys;
    };
    this.remove = function (key) {
        if (this.containsKey(key)) {
            this.previous = this.items[key];
            this.length--;
            delete this.items[key];
            return this.previous;
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    };
    this.values = function () {
        var values = [];
        for (var k in this.items) {
            if (this.containsKey(k)) {
                values.push(this.items[k]);
            }
        }
        return values;
    };
    this.each = function (fn) {
        for (var k in this.items) {
            if (this.containsKey(k)) {
                fn(k, this.items[k]);
            }
        }
    };
    var previous = undefined;
}
return HashTable;
```

Like this, Typescript having predefined code? or i need to rewrite these codes from JS to TS? is there any simple property or class for this **HashTable** in typescript?

Or any other properties in TS to do the same **HashTable** functionality?

Comment: In my humble opinion, this seems like an over kill. JS objects {} are meant to work like as a hash as well. It contains all the equivalent functions which have defined

Comment: Use `Map`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: You want this code converted to typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use Typescript.Collections.HashTable in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751766/is-there-a-way-to-use-typescript-collections-hashtable-in-my-code)

Answer (score 1):

Modern JavaScript has three options:

- `Map`, is closest to HashTable to my knowlage. It main advantage is that it’s keys may be of type `Object`.
- `Set`, it is basically an unique array.
- `Object` also known an `{}`. Key value store.

I would suggest to use object, but if your keys need to be object, use the `Map`.

---

JavaScript `Object`, or `{}`, is about 20x faster than `Map`. So use `Map` only if you need to use objects as keys.

Comment: Is possible to convert my JS code to TS by using your suggested map object?

Comment: @Raja I don't really understand your question... To convert JS to TS, just rename file and set up compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Map is probably the right answer as suggested above, but maybe a hashmap with types looks something like this would work:

```
{ [key: string]: Type; }

or

{ [key: number]: Type; }
```